# Looking for the property name used to toggle to show user picture in SharePoint list field settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, modern-experience, pnp-powershell

For a given SharePoint list column of type User there's a column setting, a toggle that allows to show the user profile pictures instead of names only.

I was looking to toggle this via PowerShell but I've been unable to find the property in any of the `SPField` classes in the  [MSFT docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms438369(v=office.14)).

Has anyone done this? So I'm using PnP PowerShell with `Set-PnPField -List $listIdentity -Identity $fieldInternalName -Values @{ 'PHOTO-TOGGLE-PROPERTY' = $true }`.

It works with other properties but I don't know the one for the photo toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try settings `UserDisplayOptions` property to `'NamePhoto'`

```
'UserDisplayOptions' = 'NamePhoto'
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much.